# Uploading two files in single page in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django.I want to upload two files in single page.I have created form for uploading one file.But with same code I have tried upload two files by making some changes.But I can't get it .

Please help me to submitting two files in one submit button in a single page

**views.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.conf import settings

from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

from django.conf.urls import url

#import csv

def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        #request.FILES['myfile'] and request.FILES["myfile1"]:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        #myfile1=request.FILES["myfile1"]
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        #filename1=fs.save(myfile1.name, myfile1)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        #uploaded_file_url1 = fs.url(filename1)
        #data = [row for row in csv.reader(myfile.read().splitlines())]

        return render(request, 'myapp/simple_upload.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url,
                      })

        #upload_file = request.FILES['upload_file']
        #data = [row for row in csv.reader(upload_file.read().splitlines())]

    return render(request, 'myapp/simple_upload.html')
def home(request):
    return render(request,'myapp/home.html')
```

**html**

```
  <!doctype>
<html>

    {% block content %}
    <body>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <form action="{% url "home" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row">
                <label for="fileupload" class="btn btn-primary  col-md-2 col-sm-4 uploadBtn" >Upload GSTR 2A</label><br>
                <input type="file" class="fileupload" id="fileupload" name="myfile" required="True">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2" style="text-align:center">
                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle checkIcon"></i>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2">
                    <p class="cancel">X</p>
                </div>
            </div>
     <div class="col-md-12">
              <form action="{% url "home" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                    <label for="fileupload" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 uploadBtn" >Upload Purchase Account</label><br>
                    <input type="file" class="fileupload" id="fileupload" name="myfile" required="True" >
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                     <a"<p class="cancel">X</p><a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="buttonGroup">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary recBtn">Reconcile</button>&nbsp;<span class="backBtn"> Back</span>
</div>     
      </form>
        </div>
         {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Why you don't just add an other input to your form and process it in your view?

Comment: Here I didn't used forms.py. I am asking how to modify my view and html to upload two files

Answer (score 1):

You only need to have two type file inputs inside the form, and get it in the view exactly like the first you created, like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" required="True">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <input type="file" name="myfile2">
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

and in your views, you get it and save it like the first one:

```
myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
myfile2 = request.FILES['myfile2']
```

In case you need to add the input file outsite the form, you need to add the "form" attribute to the input file. like this:

```
    <input type="file" name="myfile2" form="FORM_ID">
```

just replace FORM_ID with the id of your form.

Comment: Thank you @Nazkter. Now I want upload two different types files for above edited html.Now,Help me with this html to upload two different type of file